# Why Figure is not displayed in the latex file and text is shown instead of it

Tags: latex, figure

I am newbie in latex and trying to add figure into the latex file as follows:

```
\documentclass{bmcart}

%%% Load packages
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\def\includegraphic{}
\def\includegraphics{}

\startlocaldefs
\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics{figures/GBMfigure3.jpg}
    \caption{show the results of the different settings for the parameters of the penalty model for solving the problem \ref{q11}.}
    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But, the figure is not displayed and the text itself is displayed instead of the figure, for example the resulted file is as below:

[image]

So, what's the solution of that issue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\def\includegraphics{}` you redefine the command to do nothing. If you want it to include your image, don't do such a redefinition.

```
\documentclass{bmcart}

%%% Load packages
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%\def\includegraphic{}
%\def\includegraphics{}

\startlocaldefs
\endlocaldefs

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{show the results of the different settings for the parameters of the penalty model for solving the problem \ref{q11}.}
    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]